# which getElement function to click button?

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out how to click this button

```
<input class="button" type="submit" name="checkout" value="Check out">
```

by using this function

```
document.getElementBy????('????').click()
```

or should another function be used?

Comment: `document.getElementsByName("checkout")[0]`, perhaps?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want to use JQuery?  It's straight forward to use JQuery.

Comment: @StanCromlish Is there a specific reason why you can't use js or why you want to import a whole library for accessing an element..?

Comment: If it's not needed, then I wouldn't import the library for a single instance of accessing an element. JQuery makes clicking elements a lot easier.  So, if it's one element, not at all.  But, if this is just the tip of the iceberg of elements needing click events then I'd probably import JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.getElementsByName('checkout')[0].click()`

You can also use `document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

You can add an id in the input and use dcoument.getElementById or you can use document.getElementsByClassName which'll return you an array.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this for javascript

```
document.getElementById("nameofid");
```

Add an id on your element in the dom and add onclick="(javascript here)" attribute

```
<input class="button" type="submit" id="nameofid" name="checkout" value="Check out">
```

Add a function in the javascript to be called by the button using onclick attribute

```
function myfunction(){
var myvar = document.getElementById("nameofid");
//you may adjust its properties by calling myvar.nameofproperty
//or even call a method myvar.nameofmethod
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to be very sure, you should just give your button  a unique ID:

```
<input id="myCheckoutButton" class="button" name="checkout" value="Check out" />

document.getElementById("myCheckoutButton").click();
```

Basically for your problem and assuming you cannot modify html for some sinister reason...

```
document.getElementsByName
```

Would be your choice, howver this works only if you are 100% sure that there is only one element with this name on your document. If its not, it is a little bit tricky but works aswell:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByName("checkout").length; i++) {
    if(document.getElementsByName("checkout")[i].value == "Check out") {
        document.getElementsByName("checkout")[i].trigger("click");
    }
}
```

But the very-best option if you are able to implement and use jQuery in your page:

By name:

```
$(".checkout[name=checkout]").trigger("click");
```

Or by class and comparing value if you have multiple elements:

```
$(".checkout").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Check out")) {
        $(this).trigger("click");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several. The choice comes down to how specific do you want and/or need to be.

Most specific is `getElementById()` which will require you to have an id on the element. You can only have one on the page and is very specific.

If you have more than on *component* on the page and want to attach an event to each one the what you want is to use `getElementsByClass()` which will return an array of all the elements that have that class.

Finally, if you want to reference form elements you can use the name attribute to manage checkboxes and radio elements. It helps lower the specificity of using a unique id without having to add extra classes to every form element: `getElementsByName()` which (like `getElementsByClass()` returns an array of elements. Managing the difference between text inputs and checkbox inputs however is a topic for another question.